# Getting Zero in out as value of shared memory variable

Tags: c, memory-management, fork, ipc, shared-memory

I have a parent program which will fork the following child program and increment, display, decrement and display the variable 'test' (initially 0) 15 times. I tried to run it a lot of times and see what output I get after every few lines, however I'm not able to know how my 'test' variable is showing only zero, 15 times.

```
    //Include required preprocessors
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SHARED_MEM 1024 //shared memory size

int main(void)
{
    /* The child process' new program. This program replaces the parent's */
    /* program when 'fork()' is called */
    printf("Process[%d]: child in execution ... \n",getpid());

    int MAX = 15;
    int shmID, shmID2;
    key_t key = 1234, key2 = 2345;
    int *test, *counter;

    shmID = shmget(key, SHARED_MEM, 0666);

    printf("\nShmID: %d", shmID);

    shmID2 = shmget(key2, SHARED_MEM, 0666);

    printf("\nshmID2: %d", shmID2);

    test = (int *) shmat(shmID, 0, 0);
    counter = (int *) shmat(shmID2, 0, 0);

    printf("\ntEST before assignment: %d", *test);
    printf("\nCounter: %d", *counter);

    *test = 0;
    *counter = 1;

    printf("\ntest: %d", *test);
    printf("\nCounter%d", *counter);

    printf("\nAlmost there...");
    if (*counter == 1){
        for(int i=0; i < MAX; i++){
            printf("\MAX: %d", MAX);
            printf("%d", *test);
            *test++;
        }
    *counter++; //to enter second condition of second child process
    printf("\nCounter: %d", counter);
    }
    else if(*counter == 2){
        for(int j = 0; j < MAX; j++){
        printf("%d", *test);
        *test++;
        }
    *counter--;
    }

    sleep(1);
    printf("Process[%d]: child terminating ... \n", getpid());

    shmdt(test);
    shmdt(counter);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see several things.

1. Independently of how is code structured, **I'd check if there's an error in shmget and shmat**:
   I'd change

   shmID = shmget(key, SHARED_MEM, 0666) 
   shmID2 = shmget(key2, SHARED_MEM, 0666);

by

```
if ( (shmID = shmget(key, SHARED_MEM, 0666)) < 0)  
{
    perror("shmget"); 
    exit(1); 
}  
if ( (shmID2 = shmget(key2, SHARED_MEM, 0666) < 0)  
{
    perror("shmat");
    exit(1); 
}
```

---

2. Note that you're creating SHM with `0666` privileges but without `IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL`.
   I recommend you create first time with `IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666` flags.

---

3. In the same way that 1st point, I'll check also problems with shmat:

See example for `test`. Should be the same for `counter`.

```
if ((test = (int *) shmat(shmID, 0, 0)) == -1) 
{
   perror("shmat");
   exit(1);
}
```

---

You can check in cli if there's something wrong with shm, for instance, is already created, using command `ipcs` to check or `ipcrm shm` to delete and re-initialize:

```
ipcs shm | grep [your_shm_key or shmid]
```